# SQL: What is the purpose of having "basically-null" default values?

Tags: sql, plsql

So I am working with a table with a lot of default values:

```
    CREATE TABLE BLAH.BLAH
    (
      ...
      A NUMBER(19)     DEFAULT 0    NOT NULL,
      B VARCHAR2(50)   DEFAULT ' '  NOT NULL,
      C TIMESTAMP(6)   DEFAULT '01-JAN-1900'  NOT NULL,
      ...
    )
```

I am just wondering if there is any logical purpose for setting such null-like defaults to columns that would be MUCH better (in my opinion) as being set to actual NULL.

EDIT: I am mostly irked with the varchar2 default. The others are a bit more reasonable and easier to work with. It's just a pain when a lot of the code involves trimming; where I'm getting NULL when I'm expecting a single space.

Comment: I'd have probably used NULLS - they represent the absence of a value - the reason may be because a consuming application cannot handle NULL values so it might be worth looking at the apps that consume the data

Comment: Not all things are done for a good reason.  This is one of them.

Comment: Having `' '` be the default for an empty VARCHAR seems like a bad idea too -- I'd use `''`

Comment: I think in some SQL database management systems the string `''` is treated as equivalent to `null` - so if you dislike `null` then you would also forbid using `''`...

Comment: This is probably Oracle, since it is tagged PLSQL. Oracle *is* one of those databases were the empty string `''` and `null` are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense if you understand nulls and are used to dealing with them.

In its own crazy world it has some kind of logic, since if you never have nulls the values are easier to map to programming languages (all have an integer type, but not all have a nullable integer type) and comparing for 'equality' is easier (`0 = 0`, but it is not the case that `null = null`).  But the tradeoff is that you then have to handle these magic default values with boilerplate checks in your program and in any SQL queries.

It could also be the result of some misapplied, cargo-culted 'coding standard' that forbids the use of nullable columns in the database, combined with a need to have some kind of 'unknown' value anyway.

It is true that the inclusion of nulls in SQL (and in the relational model in general) adds complexity and has been controversial.  (I do not intend to give a full rundown with citations here or to argue for any particular point of view; I'm just saying that these arguments exist.)  Some suggest that if you need nullable columns you should instead fix your data model to be fully normalized; Codd thought that a single null wasn't adequate and there should be separate 'missing' and 'not applicable'.  But I'm sure that nobody who advocated getting rid of `null` suggested replacing it with a bogus `0` or `1900-01-01` value instead... So again it could be a case of misunderstanding and misapplying some design rule about not using nulls.

This kind of twisted thought process is quite common - I inherited a database where the rules forbade nullable columns (and there were APIs depending on that) but the string '?' was used instead.  In fact, there were meant to be '?' and '/' for 'missing' and 'not applicable' - following Codd's suggestion - but you can guess how much real-world data or code observed that distinction and how useful it was in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason?  There may be in some development groups.  When you say:

```
select *
from blah
where timestamp <> date '2015-01-01'
```

You might want the query to return the default values.  If the default is `NULL`, then the query will not return them.  If the default is a date far in the past, then it will.

Similarly, you might not want to clutter code with lots of `or X is null`.  This can be more than an aesthetic issue.  The presence of `or` in `where` and `on` provides opportunities for code mistakes (due to missing parentheses) and can confuse the optimizer.

I am *not* saying that the use of such defaults is a best practice.  `NULL` is such an important part of the SQL language that anyone writing production code should know how to deal with it.  However, there are good reasons for the style you mention.